# auto refresh without blinking jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

i have two php file, i am fetching data from database in one file and getting all those JSON encoded data in another php file using .getJSON() method. I want to refresh the whole page without blinking or flickering.
any suggestion ?? Thanx in advance :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already using `.getJSON`, which is an AJAX function. So you can use the same thing inside `setInterval`, which repeats it in a frequent interval of time:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $(element).html(""); // Clear the previous code.
  $.getJSON();         // Your getJSON code.
}, 1000);
```

This will update the DOM without refreshing page, with new data, every second.

Comment: I am using appendTo method inside .getJSON .. so its adding all those data over and over again after set time interval .. any suggestion how to fix that !!

Comment: @Ujjwalkaushik I got your email. `:)`